# Service Fabric - Trace statements not logging

Tags: azure, trace, azure-service-fabric

How can I set up `Trace.Trace*` (`Information`, `Warning`, `Error` etc.) to save in the Service Fabric logs? The only option I found was to use `ServiceEventSource` to send messages but that would involve revamping a lot of code to move away from Trace statements.

Is there any listener I can use to forward Trace statements to ServiceEventSource? Or anything simpler?

Comment: Maybe you can use https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow to reroute trace message to the ServiceEventSource. You will need to write an output for it since an EventSource is not provided out of the box but that is a straightforward job.

Comment: Thanks I will try that first thing tomorrow!

Answer (score 2):

[EventFlow](https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow) (as mentioned in comments by Peter Bons) combined with [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/services/application-insights/) could be a good solution for you. It easy to setup EventFlow to listen to your existing Trace statements and then forward it to Application Insighs where you can monitor the execution of your services.

Setting up EventFlow is very easy, just add the NuGet `Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow` to your service project. Then in the `eventflowconfig.json` add Trace as an input and Application Insights as an output:

```
{
"inputs": [
    {
        "type": "Trace",
        "traceLevel": "Warning"
    }
],
"filters": [],
"outputs": [
    {
        "type": "ApplicationInsights",
        "instrumentationKey": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
    }
],
"schemaVersion": "2016-08-11",
"extensions": []
```

}

Now you just setup an Application Insights instance in your Azure account and change the `instrumentationKey` to the one of your AI instance.

[image: application insights settings]

After that you can start modifying your EventFlow configuration to extract specific Request and Metric data from your Traces (if you have that type of info in your traces) then you can start visualizing it or searching for specific types of traces in th AI dashboard.

Note that Application Insights only retains logs for 7 days by default. If you meed to keep your traces longer you can change the AI tier and you can [activate Continuous Export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-export-telemetry).

Answer (score -2):

```
namespace MassProcessing
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is the entry point of the service host process.
        /// </summary>
        private static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                // The ServiceManifest.XML file defines one or more service type names.
                // Registering a service maps a service type name to a .NET type.
                // When Service Fabric creates an instance of this service type,
                // an instance of the class is created in this host process.
                using (var diagnosticsPipeline = ServiceFabricDiagnosticPipelineFactory.CreatePipeline("EngageServiceFabric-MassProcessing-DiagnosticsPipeline"))
                {
                    ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("MassProcessingType",
                    context => new MassProcessing(context)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                    ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(MassProcessing).Name);

                    // Prevents this host process from terminating so services keep running.
                    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```